# Prove or disprove if ma ≡ mb (mod n), then a ≡ b (mod n) for all positive integers a, b, m, n.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove/disprove if ma ≡ mb (mod n), then a ≡ b (mod n) for all positive integers a, b, m, n.
I know the fact that

```
if (m,n) = d, then ma ≡ mb (mod n) if and only if a≡b (mod n/d)
```

I have no idea what should I do?

Comment: $x\to mx\,$ is injective ($1$-to-$1)\!\!\iff\!\! m\,$ is invertible $\bmod n\!\!\iff\!\! \gcd(m,n) = 1,\,$ see my answer in linked dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in the general case. A counter example:

Modulo $6$ we have

$$3\cdot 1\equiv 3\cdot 5\pmod 6$$

The case where it works is when $m$ is not a zero divisor modulo $n$. It is the case when $(m,n)=1$ that is to say $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.